# How to change a Pytorch CNN to take color images instead of black and white?

Tags: python, image, conv-neural-network, pytorch

[This code](https://github.com/harveyslash/Facial-Similarity-with-Siamese-Networks-in-Pytorch/blob/master/Siamese-networks-medium.ipynb) I found has a neural net that is setup to take black and white images. (It's a siamese network but that part's not relevant). When I change it to take my images and NOT convert them to black and white I get an error shown below.
I tried changing the first Conv2d, the sixth line down from a 1 to a 3

```
class SiameseNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SiameseNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.cnn1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ReflectionPad2d(1),
            # was nn.Conv2d(1, 4, kernel_size=3),
            nn.Conv2d(3, 4, kernel_size=3),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(4),

            nn.ReflectionPad2d(1),
            nn.Conv2d(4, 8, kernel_size=3),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(8),

            nn.ReflectionPad2d(1),
            nn.Conv2d(8, 8, kernel_size=3),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(8))

        self.fc1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(8*300*300, 500),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),

            nn.Linear(500, 500),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),

            nn.Linear(500, 5))

    def forward_once(self, x):
        output = self.cnn1(x)
        output = output.view(output.size()[0], -1)
        output = self.fc1(output)
        return output

    def forward(self, input1, input2):
        output1 = self.forward_once(input1)
        output2 = self.forward_once(input2)
        return output1, output2
```

My error when the images are NOT converted to black and white and remain in color.

```
RuntimeError: invalid argument 0: Sizes of tensors must match  
except in dimension 0. Got 3 and 1 in dimension 1 at  
/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch-nightly_1542963753679/work/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorMoreMath.cpp:1319
```

I checked the shapes of the images as arrays (right before they go into the model) as black and white vs in color...

B&W

```
torch.Size([1, 1, 300, 300])
```

In color

```
torch.Size([1, 3, 300, 300])
```

Here is a link to a Jupyter Notebook of the entire original code I am working with... https://github.com/harveyslash/Facial-Similarity-with-Siamese-Networks-in-Pytorch/blob/master/Siamese-networks-medium.ipynb

EDIT: UPDATE: I seemed to have solved it by converting the images to RBG in the SiameseNetworkDataset part of the code

```
img0 = img0.convert("L")
```

changed to

```
img0 = img0.convert("RGB")
```

I just had the line commented out before and thought this left it in RGB but it was something else the model didn't understand.
Also, the change in the OP was needed.

```
nn.Conv2d(1, 4, kernel_size=3),
```

changed to

```
nn.Conv2d(3, 4, kernel_size=3),
```

If you'd like to answer with an explaination of what the model is doing that makes it clear I'll give you the green check. Don't really understand nn.Conv2d

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be in fully connected part below:

```
self.fc1 = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(8*100*100, 500),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),

        nn.Linear(500, 500),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),

        nn.Linear(500, 5))
```

It seems the output of cnn is of shape`[8,300,300]` and not `[8,100,100]`

To solve this either, change input image to `[n_channel, 100,100]` or change the size of input size of fc-layer to `8*300*300`

Comment: Sorry, the 8*100*100 was in the code but I changed it in my code to 8*300*300. I just copied from the original instead of my modified code I changed so the model would not throw away image quality. It's actually the last line, nn.Linear(500, 5)) I just changed to (500,7) and now it trains RGB instead of B&W images. I'll give you the green check if you want to edit your answer to explain how this works, maybe link to an explanation. I still don't fully understand or know if input needs changed somewhere else.

Comment: Are you trying to say if the final layer was (500,5) it wasn't working and with (500,7) it is working?

The code (at least what you have shown, forward or forward_once) works for me with both (500,5) as well as (500,7)

Comment: Yes, but now I see that's just what I thought was happening. (500, 5) to (500,7), but now I think I just sent a black and white images through. That wasn't the solution. You got the entire notebook and commented out         img0 = img0.convert("L") and sent color images through the network? I haven't been able to put color images through this after a few days of trying. I'm sure it's a 'channel' issue - if I only knew how to change it/ where it was.

Comment: I am not sure what are you looking for. I can see the notebook and can't think why it won't work? There could be multiple failure reasons. I don't know what exact inputs you passed what losses you used. As far as I understand your model is working fine. So where are you getting the error? which block or which line of code?

Comment: You can't think of why it wouldn't work - - it's when I prevent the notebook from converting the image to black and white how I showed in my last comment. This happens in the 4th cell down that starts with 'class SiameseNetworkDataset(Dataset): Like I said it's expecting 1 channel (grey) but now I'm giving it 3 channels (Red, Blue, Green).

Comment: Can you please add what changes you made to that code. I mean the Dataset Class?

Comment: I figured it out, along with my attempt to fix the problem in the OP by changing the Conv2d from 'nn.Conv2d(1, 4, kernel_size=3)'  to  'nn.Conv2d(3, 4, kernel_size=3)', (which was needed), my problem was I was not converting the image to img0 = img0.convert("RGB"). I was just commenting out img0 = img0.convert("L") which was converting it to black and white. Now I'm training. I don't know if you would be able to give an answer like this or if I should delete the question.